# Rolling with additional batch policy does not work and diapered from Beanstalk console

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

Rolling with additional batch policy diapered from Beanstalk console and it is not visible from `Rolling updates and deployments` page.
From the main `Configuration` page everything looks fine.

The main problem is that from time to time when I am deploying my app by using this way of deployment it just does not work at all and `All at once` policy is used :(

[image]
[image] 
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case I believe the best approach is to get in touch with the [AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/) team and inform this error.